# Spring MongoDB Aggregation Group

Tags: spring, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I want to group data by condition.
Here is the data

```
[
  {
    name: AAA,
    age: 14,
    country: us
  },
  {
    name: BBB,
    age: 13,
    country: us
  },
  {
    name: CCC,
    age: 12,
    country: null
  },
  {
    name: DDD,
    age: 12,
    country: null
  }
]
```

If country is null, group by age
If country is not null, group by country

I would like to get the result like below

```
{
  country: us
  [
    {
      name: AAA,
      age: 13
    },
    {
      name: BBB,
      age: 14
    }
  ]
},
{
  age: 12,
  country: null
  [
    name: CCC,
    name: DDD,
  ]
}
```

Hope to get help

Comment: have u tried anything ? can u show the code ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You try this method

```
 [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$country",
          people: {
            $push: {
              name: "$name",
              age: "$age"
            }
          },
          age: {
            $addToSet: "$age"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          country: "$_id",
          people: 1,
          age: {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    $size: "$age"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$age",
                  0
                ]
              },
              "else": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aGnd2Uq8VsD)